# How to modify Google Form Response with File Upload

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have successfully generated an edit link for my Google Form response (with File Upload). When I open this link, I can edit my answer to all questions except the File Upload item. I cannot delete the uploaded file or upload an updated version of that file. Am I missing a setting or could there be a GAS code to enable me to modify the uploaded file in Google Form? Thanks!

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: Hi @jess I am not encountering an error problem and I have not used any code yet. When I edit my Form Response, I can edit my answers to all the questions except my answer to the File Upload Item. I cannot delete the file I uploaded or replace it with a new file. Is there a setting where I can able to edit my File Upload answer or is there an available code for this one? Thanks!

Comment: This is a great question! I have just encountered the same scenario myself. If you use file upload feature in google forms you are not able to edit the response.

Answer (score 0):

there is no chance of editing the file uploaded in google forms. you can edit only the answers that you have answere